# exactly what trigger doesn't work

Tags: sql-server

friends I'm writing a trigger, but there is something I missed or did I get it wrong I don't know. 
the problem is probably with the code to get the code I wrote There is a problem. But I wasn't sure. 
the purpose of the inventory when he enters the trigger, add it to the part of your debt when you remove the pieces.
when added Act the same way

```
create trigger StokHareketGirisCikis
on StokHareket
after insert,update,delete
as
declare @stokKodu nvarchar(50),@gc int,@stokId int,@adet int
if exists (select * from deleted)
begin 
    select @stokId=id from deleted  
    select @stokKodu=(select StokKodu from StokKarti where id=@stokId),@adet=Miktar,@gc=GC from deleted
    if @gc=1
    begin
        update StokToplam set borc-=@adet where stokKodu=@stokKodu
        end
        else
        update StokToplam set alacak-=@adet where stokKodu=@stokKodu
end
if exists(select * from inserted)
begin
select @stokId=id from inserted
select @stokKodu=(select StokKodu from StokKarti where id=@stokId),@adet=Miktar,@gc=GC from inserted
    if @gc=1
    begin
        update StokToplam set borc+=@adet where stokKodu=@stokKodu
        end
        else
        update StokToplam set alacak+=@adet where stokKodu=@stokKodu
end
```

Comment: totally unclear

Comment: Tip: Avoid triggers. In most cases is an attempt to correct bad design.

Comment: I don't understand why you were downvoted it is a pretty good question, here is my up.

Comment: At first I think to put a long comment, but than I realized that it was more suited as an answer, please, take a look.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I took care of the problem. ' StokId ' ' StokKodu ' I changed it to. works just fine.

```
create trigger [dbo].[StokHareketGirisCikis]
on [dbo].[StokHareket]
after insert,update,delete
as
declare @stokKodu nvarchar(50),@gc int,@adet int
if exists (select * from deleted)
begin   
    select @stokKodu=StokKodu,@adet=Miktar,@gc=GC from deleted
    if @gc=1
    begin
        update StokToplam set borc-=@adet where stokKodu=@stokKodu
        end
        else
        update StokToplam set alacak-=@adet where stokKodu=@stokKodu
end
if exists(select * from inserted)
begin
select @stokKodu=StokKodu,@adet=Miktar,@gc=GC from inserted
    if @gc=1
    begin
        update StokToplam set borc+=@adet where stokKodu=@stokKodu
        end
        else
        update StokToplam set alacak+=@adet where stokKodu=@stokKodu
end
```

@gofr1 thank you so much

Comment: And what if there were 3 rows with different `StokKodu` inserted in one time? Your trigger will operate only with one of them, it is very bad approach as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is you are using 1 row (f.e. `select @stokId=id from deleted`), but there maybe more rows in `inserted` and `deleted`. You don't need to use variables to take values from this tables, use JOIN.

F.e. this part:

```
select @stokId=id from deleted  
select @stokKodu=(select StokKodu from StokKarti where id=@stokId),@adet=Miktar,@gc=GC from deleted
if @gc=1
begin
    update StokToplam set borc-=@adet where stokKodu=@stokKodu
    end
    else
    update StokToplam set alacak-=@adet where stokKodu=@stokKodu
```

Could be rewrited like:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    select  sk.StokKodu,
            d.Miktar,
            d.GC
    from deleted d
    inner join StokKarti sk
        ON sk.id = d.id
)

update st 
set borc-=c.Miktar
FROM StokToplam st
INNER JOIN cte с
    ON c.stokKodu=st.stokKodu
        AND c.GC = 1

update st 
set alacak-=c.Miktar
FROM StokToplam st
INNER JOIN cte с
    ON c.stokKodu=st.stokKodu
        AND c.GC != 1
```

Comment: I have to do this job without trigger?

Comment: If you need this changes to be made immediatly - use trigger, if you can do this once in an hour F.e. better use stored procedure and job with hourly schedule.

Comment: now it has to be done. because at that moment I need to see the number of the remaining stock.

Comment: Then use trigger approach, but use ALL rows from `inserted` and `deleted`!

Comment: And I hope you remember that on UPDATE both tables are used, so if you don't need deleted on UPDATE add some checking.

Comment: If my answer was helpful feel free to accept/upvote it.

Comment: I do try and get back to you the code that you write. for now, thank you.